# EJB depending on another EJB?

Tags: java, ejb, jboss7.x, jndi, ejb-3.1

I'm using Jboss 7 and have two separate deployments that both contain singleton EJBs.

I need the one EJB to have access to the other EJB and be able to call its methods, however, when the app server starts up and attempts to deploy them both it seems to make no guarantees about which one gets started first (even if you set `Dependencies: deployment.xxx.jar` on one to the other).

I don't seem to be able to use the `@DependsOn` annotation, since this names a particular EJB which doesn't seem to be doable across separate deployments, leaving me with `@EJB(lookup=JNDI_STRING)` as my only option. This injection, however, doesn't seem to guarantee that the the EJB you're depending on will actually be *started* when the lookup happens, resulting in a NPE. Obviously, this also happens if you simply just use an `InitialContext` from the `@PostContruct` method to lookup the second EJB over JNDI.

So, I basically need to guarantee that one EJB in one deployment will be started before another EJB in another deployment, on the same appserver. I think it'd probably work if I were to lazily initialize the dependant EJB from, say, a `HttpServlet` set to run-on-startup, but this is not ideal.

Perhaps there's some sensible method of doing this that i'm missing? I don't really want to have to *poll* the EJB until it's started.

Comment: why not lazy load the reference, looking it up the first time it is needed?

Comment: @jtahlborn it's a sort of registrar/registree set up, so it's basically needed as soon as possible, so it's awkward to just wait some arbitrary period of time and then try the lookup

Comment: have you looked through stuff like [this thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/175625?start=15&tstart=1&_sscc=t)?

Comment: @jtahlborn the `jboss-deployment-structure` approach should be the same as the `Dependencies: x` approach mentioned in the question - this does not seem to guarantee that the thing you depend on has actually started - it just seems to give you access to its classes. The post just after mentions a few interesting things but i'm not sure it's referring to entirely separate deployments (i was fairly sure, for example, that you could not use the @DependsOn annotation across TLDs since it just takes a name)

Comment: Are the EJBs in different .EARs?

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure in the jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
   <deployment>
       <dependencies>
           <module name="deployment.app1.ear" />
       </dependencies>
   </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Source [mastertheboss](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-deploy/configuring-jboss-as-7-deployment-order)